# How do you solve this limit $ \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^m-\sin^nx}{x^{n+2}} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is like this :

> How do you solve $$ \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^m-\sin^nx}{x^{n+2}} $$ for different values of $ n \in \Bbb N $.

Now, what i've started doing is to add $$ \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^m-x^n+x^n-\sin^nx}{x^{n+2}} $$ then i split the limit into two limits like this $$ \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^m-x^n}{x^{n+2}} + \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^n-\sin^nx}{x^{n+2}} $$ and i was thinking for the second limit to apply  the formula : $(a-b)^n$ . The problem is that i don't know what to do with the first limit which has $x^m$, at first i thought that i was  a mistake in my textbook, but i am not sure .

Comment: Do you know Taylor expansions?

Comment: this is actually a highschool problem . I've heard of taylor expansions but i was looking for a different approach

Comment: Well, series expansion works best in this case, as you need to find the relationship between m and n. And in your case m =n to get a finite answer

Comment: So, how is it that this problem is from a highschool book ? And if that is the case, you are saying there is no other way to solve  this than  to use taylor expasions ?

Comment: I see, so i should treat m as being equal to n ?

Comment: @Jon9 Well m=n is certainly clear and I am not saying there is no other way. Squeeze play theorem could help getting a solution.

Comment: Is it okay if i use L'Hopital's rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^m-\sin^nx}{x^{n+2}} $$

For limit to exist finitely $m=n$ so we get $$ \lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{x^n-\sin^nx}{x^{n+2}} $$

$$ =\lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{(x-\sin x)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\sin x+\dots+\sin^{n-1}x)}{x^{n+2}} $$

$$ =\lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{(x-\sin x)}{x^{3}} \lim _{x\to 0}\:\: \frac{(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\sin x+\dots+\sin^{n-1}x)}{x^{n-1}} $$

$$=\frac{1}{3!}n = \frac{n}{6}.$$

First limit we can solve using exp, L'Hôpital and second is standard limit. If L'Hôpital is also not allowed then in the first limit

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\:\:\frac{(x-\sin x)}{x^{3}}$$

take a substitution $x=3t$.

https://socratic.org/questions/how-can-i-evaluate-lim-x-0-sinx-x-x-3-without-using-l-hopital-s-rule#526214

Answer (score 2):

The limit exists if $m=n$, then
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^n-\sin^n x}{x^{n+2}} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n\right)$$ 
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\left(1-x^2/6+x^4/120+O(x^6\right)^n\right) =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^2}[1-(1-nx^2/6+nx^4/120+n O(x^6)].$$
$$\implies L=\frac{n}{6}.$$
Lastly we have used the binomial approximation when $x \rightarrow 0$